# emacs el-get does not load packages

Tags: emacs

Using Emacs 24.3 on OS X, I have setup el-get as described. I am able to install, remove, and init packages using the el-get-* commands.

However, none of the packages ever actually load. The simple example I use is for the package 'ascii-table'. I do the following:

```
M-x el-get-install ascii-table
M-x el-get-init ascii-table
```

But when I do

```
M-x ascii-table
```

Emacs says it is not found. If I explicitly eval the ascii-table.el file that was downloaded by el-get, it works as expected.

Is there something I must do, after installing a package, to actually use the package? Or do I still need to put the necessary load-file or whatever in my init.el file to load the packages?

It sounds like, from the el-get documentation, that there was nothing else that needed to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instruct `el-get` to require features from a package by adding the property `features` to the package's recipe file. From the documentation (do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`el-get-sources`<kbd>RET</kbd>)

> :features
>
> List of features el-get will `require' for you.

For your particular case do <kbd>M-x</kbd>`el-get-find-recipe-file`<kbd>RET</kbd>`ascii-table`<kbd>RET</kbd>, this open ascii-table's recipe file for you, then add the following to the recipe

```
:features (ascii-table)
```

The full recipe will be

```
(:name ascii-table
       :auto-generated t
       :type emacswiki
       :description "simple ASCII table"
       :website "https://raw.github.com/emacsmirror/emacswiki.org/master/ascii-table.el"
       :features (ascii-table))
```

My advice would be not edit the original recipe but keep this in your personal recipes folder to avoid any conflicts when updating `el-get`.

That said you can always manually load a package, see @Drew's comment

Answer (score 1):

Is el-get supposed to load libraries?  I doubt it.

To load a library, put `(require 'FEATURE-NAME)` in your init file, where `FEATURE` is the feature `provide`d by the library.  If it does not provide any feature, then use the file name instead (between `"` chars).